# jquery scroll opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function() {
$(document).scroll(function() {


var windowscroll = $(this).scrollTop();


if($(window).scrollTop() >= 900)
{
 $("#scrollhome").css("opacity",(1-($(window).scrollTop()-900)/75))
}
 else
 $("#scrollhome").css("opacity",1)



 if(windowscroll > 900 && windowscroll < 1300)
 {
 $("#scrollabout").css("opacity",($(window).scrollTop()-900)/75)
 }
 else
$("#scrollabout").css("opacity",0)

if(windowscroll > 1200 && windowscroll < 1500)
 {
    $("#scrollabout").css("opacity", (-1($(window).scrollTop()-1200)/75))
    $("#scrolldesign").css("opacity",($(window).scrollTop()-1200)/75)
 }
 else
    $("#scrolldesign").css("opacity",0)


 });




 });
```

the first overlap between scrollhome and scrollabout works nice but when it comes to the second overlap between scrollabout and scroll design i don't know how to hide the scrollabout funktion in a smooth way again, i need help! how can i make the scrollabout hidden again using scrolltop?

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS along with the jQuery.

Comment: Consider using http://jsbin.com/ for your example.

Comment: i guess he has a really tall page and some static menu somewhere that based on the scrolling position it fades in/out the buttons in the menu that when clicked scroll back to whatever region

Answer (score 0):

you misstyped it as `-1($(window).....`. it should also be `1-($(window)`